# hcitool lescan (BLE or any scan, say, hcitool, gatttool, btdevice-l, etc...) in docker under Non-Privileged & Non-host Network mode is possible?

Tags: docker, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am a newbie to docker. For a specific task,

**I am failing to scan BLE / BlueZ in docker under Non-Privileged & Non-Host network mode.**
These are my results > (in Debian-Jessie-8.8.0 Host and debian:jessie docker image)
`root1@73ab53a9268e:/# hciconfig -a`
--> `Can't open HCI socket.: Operation not permitted`
and

`root1@73ab53a9268e:/# bt-device -l` -->
`Couldn't connect to DBus system bus: Could not connect: Connection refused`

another image ==>>
`root2@0d208802d44a:/# hciconfig -a`
--> `Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol`

I even gave ALL-CAP permissions for docker on Host but still could not make it.

`docker run --name container-ID --cap-add=ALL -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock -v /dev:/host/dev -v /proc:/host/proc:ro -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro -v /usr:/host/usr:ro Image-ID`

> So, is it possible by any chance to scan BLE / BlueZ  (say, hcitool, gatttool, btdevice-l, etc...) in docker under Non-Privileged & Non-Host network mode ?

Answer (score 2):

Successfully Started DBus/Bluetooth Services inside docker container and scan bluetooth devices by adding **--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, --cap-add=NET_ADMIN** and **--net=host** flags/permission

`docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --net=host -it debian:jessie`

(Succeeded without **--privileged** mode) Now just looking to start bluetooth service by "Not sharing the Host Networking Namespace" (customising **--net=host** to private network)